# An isomorphism about the central localization of a monoid

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups, localization

Let $M$ be a monoid and $K$ an algebraically closed field. Then we can get a semigroup algebra $KM$. Assume the element $z$ is a central and regular element of $KM$, when we consider the central localization $M\langle z\rangle^{-1}$, we have
\begin{align}
M\langle z\rangle^{-1}\cong M/(z=1)\times \langle z, z^{-1}\rangle.
\end{align}
My question is how to proof this isomorphism? Any answers will be appreciated.

Comment: can you describe the central localization $M<z>^{-1}$ more clear?

Comment: @Penson, you can see this paper on page 316, http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1974-046-03/S0002-9939-1974-0352164-0/S0002-9939-1974-0352164-0.pdf